# Condo HOA/maintainence fee versus upkeeping a house

Tags: real-estate, house

How does the maintenance fee of a condo compare to up keeping a house where there is no maintenance fee.  Does upkeeping a small/medium sized house cost less than the maintenance fee of buying a condo?  Some condo I looked at cost $700 per month in maintenance fee surely maintaining a house is cheaper?

Comment: A **rough** rule of thumb is to budget between 1 and 2% of home value **per year** for home repair and maintenance.  Thus, I'd say that $700/month *just* for *maintenance* is absurdly expensive (unless the HOA neglected upkeep for a long time and now is having to catch up, which should tell you something about the HOA).

Comment: @RonJohn I agree completely.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: Really not answerable, for at least two reasons.  1) The HOA pays people to do the work.  As a homeowner, you may choose to do some or all of it yourself.  2) The HOA may do things that you don't consider necessary, like maintaining common areas, pools, and the like.

Comment: Are you willing to share what the cost of the condo is? To RonJon's comment, if we see what percent it represents, we'd have a clearer picture of how reasonable it may or may not be.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica of course my comment might be biased by thinking of "suburban" townhouse-style condos, instead of high rise condos.

Comment: @RonJohn - agreed. I have a cousin in a 'condo' in NJ. It's a standalone home that could just as easily be on a public street. It has an indoor pool, outdoor pool, golf course, gym. And is worth over $1M.  A bit different from an apartment style condo, with no amenities. I'm not making a case for or against the $700. Only that with no further details, the question is not complete.

Comment: The condo is 400k and barely any good stuff (no gym very small pool) but single family houses average 1m in my area.

Answer (score 5):

> Some condo I looked at cost $700 per month in maintenance fee surely
> maintaining a house is cheaper?

HOA's vary wildly in terms of what they do with the money collected. Some provide pools/gyms, snow removal, landscaping, etc. Complicating matters further, some HOA's maintain the streets in the neighborhood/complex instead of the city/county which can mean a lower property tax assessment but higher HOA cost. It's impossible to say whether or not $700/month is reasonable without knowing what gets done with that money.

HOA records/documents are available for you to review as an owner/prospective owner (usually you'd include a condition in an offer that allows you to back out of the contract if the HOA financials are concerning to you). You can review the financials and other documents to find out what the HOA covers and ensure that there's nothing concerning going on (low reserves and high management fees are the primary red flags I've encountered).

There is a chance the association overpays for some services or that you would do some of the items yourself rather than paying someone to handle them, and much of the time there is a company hired to manage the HOA which carries significant cost. On the other hand with an HOA you can get a better per unit rates for a lot of services thanks to scale/bulk-pricing.

In my experience with a multitude of HOA's the cost is more than I would pay to maintain a comparable home myself, but only because I would do a lot of things myself that they end up paying for.

Answer (score 3):

Your condo fee includes, broadly speaking, three components:

- regular maintenance like changing lightbulbs, replacing broken things, touching up paint and such. This generally is done by a paid "handyman" whereas around your own house you provide the labour yourself.
- setting aside money for large "projects" like replacing all the carpets or repainting all the balconies. Depending on how long you live in a place, you might have years of your fees going into a "savings account" for some every-20-years maintenance project that doesn't happen while you live there at all! In theory, homeowners should do the same, but many don't.
- non-maintenance work like lawn mowing, gardening, cleaning and such which again is being done by paid people or a service, while at home the homeowner is likely to be the one doing it.

As a result the condo fees will always be more than your costs would be for the very same kind of property but where you did all the work yourself. But it's not the very same kind of property. A house has one roof per house. An apartment building has one larger roof shared by a lot more people. That might be savings for the condo. But the condo has an elevator and a parking garage and all kinds of things that the house doesn't have. It might even have a pool, a weight room, and so on that must be maintained too. I expect that overall, houses are more expensive to maintain **per unit** than apartment buildings. But that difference is small, and very much outweighed by the fact the condo pays people to do everything. That's the appeal when you buy one! You don't need to paint, mow the lawn, shovel the snow, check the pool chemicals! There are lovely flowers that you don't plant or weed! Someone else even cleans the outside of your windows once a year!

So do house owners spend or set aside 500 or 700 dollars a month for maintenance? Absolutely not. Nobody I know does. My rule of thumb is set aside enough to do your cost of your roof (an easy estimate to get) every 10 years. You will probably do it every 20 years; you save at double the rate to cover everything else you might need to do maintenance on. So if a roof would be $10,000, save $1000 a year or $80 a month for your "roof fund." It will cover a lot of stuff.

Comment: You make some good points, but the level of maintenance provided varies wildly by association, it's important to examine what specifically the HOA covers.

Answer (score 1):

> Does upkeeping a small/medium sized house cost less than the
> maintenance fee of buying a condo? Some condo I looked at cost $700
> per month in maintenance fee surely maintaining a house is cheaper?

You have to compare apples-to-apples.

If it is a condo building or buildings, then the monthly cost will include costs associated with the common property within the buildings. Stairs, elevators, and the like. There are osts to clean those areas regularly, paint them, and repair or update them.

There are also costs for the outside structure of the building. That includes the outside walls, foundation, and the roof. There can be annual costs, and capital costs that occur every decade or two. They may be required to set aside money to pay for these capital costs, by collecting a little every month.

There are also the costs associated with the grounds. They need to be mowed, fed, watered, and the like. They may also have trees, shrubs, and other plants that have to be maintained. The more land the higher the costs. They may also include walking trails and other things that have to be periodically repaired.

Parking lots can be expensive to paint, pave, and repair. Everybody pays the costs. Garages can be even more expensive.

The community can also have pools, and tennis courts which all have operations, maintenance, and capital expenses.

Now some of these things may also be had when you own a home. single family homes can belong to communities that have common ground, pools, and parking lots. They can even have their own pool.

Note then none of this covered the things inside the unit. That is always on you to repair and replace. The HOA only gets involved if your stuff inside the unit impacts those outside the unit.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here provide good thoughts in approaching this, I can provide an anecdotal account as I recently went through the process of deciding between a condo or a house.

You can calculate out the "wasted" money from each - interest, upkeep, insurance - against the equity you will gain. I used the 1% rule-of-thumb for calculations - that you'll spend 1% of your house value each year in upkeep (you should also remember that condos will also require some level of upkeep, though less than a house).

What I found was that, for instance, in a $120,000 condo vs a $220,000 house, assuming a condo HOA fee of $450 and a 20% down payment on either option, the wasted money was roughly equivalent. The monthly mortgage payment on the condo was less, but the HOA fee brings it in line with the house mortgage. The equity you gain in the house is greater. The utilities and insurance you'll pay on the house will be more, but depending on the size of the house/condo this may be negligible. One thing you should also consider is that its generally easier to sell a house than a condo. However a house is also riskier - you'll never have to suddenly replace your roof in a condo.

I ultimately purchased a smaller house, because the wasted money was similar to the condo offerings and a house affords me greater freedom to customize my property - and also because most condo HOAs in my area forbid short term rentals, which is something I wanted to do since I frequently leave town.

Answer (score -5):

When you pay for an HOA condo maintenance fee, you're paying for all the costs of maintenance ***plus*** you are usually paying for an expensive (and often unethical) management company to "manage" the property.  This can add ***significantly*** to your expenses.

Also keep in mind that these management companies often push "preferred providers" on the ignorant HOA board members (who usually have zero experience running a sizable property).  These "preferred providers" rarely offer the best prices or guarantees.  This often makes maintenance unnecessarily expensive.  Conflicts of interest are commonplace.

Finally, HOA board members are notorious for keeping HOA fees too low while they live there, thus not adequately funding reserves.  HOA management companies are typically hired by the HOA board members, so these horrible companies usually go along with the scam without firmly taking action to prevent such abuses and negligence from taking place.  So when you are paying an HOA maintenance fee, you are often also often paying for deferred or long-term maintenance that should have been paid by the previous owners.

I've known many people who have lived in HOA properties, and not a single one has anything good to say about their HOA management companies or their HOA board members.

Comment: This answer sounds like the rant of someone who has had a bad experience with a management company. Not a very objective answer to the original question.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica that high-rise condo in Miami would not have collapsed if it's HOA board had done what it's supposed to do.

Comment: RonJohn - There are something like 350k community associations in the US.  Citing one failure is meaningless.

Comment: I've lived in an HOA managed community for 20 years and have had the exact opposite experience.  Although we have an election for 1/2 the board every year, many board members have served 5-10 years.  We require a minimum of 3 bids for a contract and since it's our money that's going to be spent, no "preferred provider"  is being pushed on us.  Our reserves are well funded and our board has kept the monthly fee steady for several years at a time, grudgingly increasing it periodically due to the the ever increasing cost of living.

Comment: In every field, there are good and bad. I don't know the whole Miami story, but I do know that for such a large expense, homeowners often need to vote. Somehow Kate provided an objective answer, no rant there.

Comment: @BobBaerker Citing one success is meaningless.

Comment: @RockPaperLz - As JTP mentioned, your answer does not objectively answer the question.  RonJohn's condo comment that a catastrophic collapse of a building was the fault of and irresponsible condo association is presumptuous and premature.  It may take years to determine the cause(s).  Faulty design?  Faulty construction?  The ground sinking slowly beneath the building for decades?  It may be some time before the contributing factors are known.

Comment: @BobBaerker My point is that you were minimizing another person's important example, and then you proceeded to provide your own as evidence.  I was trying to kindly point out your hypocrisy without calling you a hypocrite.

Comment: Your problem is that you somehow believe that a catastrophic collapse of a condo in Miami has something to do with the question: **Condo HOA/maintenance fee versus upkeeping a house**.  I'll pass on 'kindly pointing out' your XXX and calling you a YYY.

Comment: @BobBaerker You wrote "Citing one failure is meaningless." and then you proceeded to cite one personal non-failure.  That's call hypocrisy, like it or not.  Everything else is red herrings you're trying to throw at the wall hoping they stick (to humourously mix metaphors).